# How to preselect first element in Dijit.form.FilteringSelect?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have Dijit.form.FilteringSelect which dynamicly loads from web service content of dropdown.

I want to preselect first element. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you creating the filtering select declaratively or programmatically?

Comment: I created filtering select programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your implementation.

If you first load data and then create `dojo/store/Memory` which feeds `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` then:

```
// sync only for dojo/store/Memory
var store = filteringSelect1.store;
filteringSelect1.set("value", store.getIdentity(store.data[0]));
```

More robust synchronous or asynchronous way would be querying the store:

```
when(store.query(function(item, index, items) {
    return index == 0;
}), function(results) {
    filteringSelect2.set("value", store.getIdentity(results[0]));
});
```

See these two example in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/DaA3a/

If your `filteringSelect` is backed up by `dojo/store/JsonRest` then your REST service must support querying by `index` (in addition to querying by `id`):

```
restStore.query({ index: 0 }).then(function(item) {
    filteringSelect1.set("value", restStore.getIdentity(item));  
});
```

See a bit more complex example (simulating such a REST service via sinon.js [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer)) at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/pGt5n/

Comment: For me, the set('value',...) was not working. What I did is: set('item', item)